# Ambigous route matches on slugified urls

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm getting an ambiguous match for uri: `Toyota-Corolla-vehicles/2` Iv'e isolated the problem down to these two routes

```
[HttpGet("{make}-vehicles/{makeId:int}")]
[HttpGet("{make}-{query}-vehicles/{makeId:int}")]
```

It looks pretty unambiguous to me. Shouldn't the uri match the route with two dashes in it?

For more context:
I'm using readable url's like this `Toyota-vehicles-in-2005`. So I can't use forward slashes for separation.

```
[HttpGet("{make}-vehicles-in-{year}/{makeId:int}")]
```

The docs state:

> Complex segments (for example, [Route("/dog{token}cat")]), are
>   processed by matching up literals from right to left in a **non-greedy**
>   way. See the source code for a description. For more information, see
>   this issue.

https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/9cea167cfac36cf034dbb780e3f783114ef94780/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/Patterns/RoutePatternMatcher.cs#L296

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/8197

Comment: It's a placeholder for a search term

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use these routes:

```
[HttpGet("{make}/vehicles/{makeId:int}")]
[HttpGet("{make}/{query}/vehicles/{makeId:int}")]
```

There is no ambiguity between `Toyota/vehicles/2` and `Toyota/Corolla/vehicles/2` in that case. In your case it has ambiguity due to fact, that `{query}` is type of `string`, so `Toyota-Corolla-vehicles` string matches both `{make}-vehicles` and `{make}-{query}-vehicles`, because we can parse it like:

1. ALL `{make}` parameter equals to `Toyota-Corolla`;
2. `{make}-{query}` equals to `Toyota-Corolla`, where `{make}` is `Toyota` and `{query}` is `Corolla` correspondingly.

So, the problem is with your character `-`. If you don't want to change your routes, you can leave only `[HttpGet("{make}-vehicles/{makeId:int}")]` and distinguish then `Toyota-Corolla` by `string.Split` method.

Comment: I need to use sluggified urls for readability. That's exaclty my problem, why does this work but the other doesn't? both have one character for seperation

Comment: @AvinKavish check the proposed method please. The problem is exactly in that separation character.

Comment: Yeah but asp net core is supposed to support separation of parameters by using string literals. It matches non-greedily by default. It is not supposed to behave the way you describe it to behave. See the quote from the docs.

Comment: Yes, seems that ASP.NET Core's routing works quite counterintuitive in such cases. Anyway, you can always use [Custom Route Constaints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-route-constraints), or even simple [Regex Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference).

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to use a regex. I've opened an issue to get some official clarification though

Comment: @AvinKavish could you post a link to the issue? It will be interesting to hear some additional clarifications also.